# Drupal 6: Parent menu item redirection to first submenu item

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a Drupal 6.22 site, with primary links like this (using Nice Menus):

```
Section 1
- Foo
- Bar
Section 2
- Page A
(...)
```

My client asked this: If a user clicks on "Section 1", the "Foo" page is shown. In other words, when clicking on any "Section" the user will be redirected to the first child of that section.

At first, I modified the menu item "Section 1" path to "section1/foo", but the breadcrumb in the Foo page (I'm using Menu Breadcrumbs) is showing:

```
Home > Section 1
```

I want the breadcrumb to show this:

```
Home > Section 1 > Foo
```

So that didn't work, so I installed the Redirect Module, defined a "section1 -> section1/foo" redirect, but I can't create menu items pointing to "section1" (it isn't an alias).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the menu array directly. Open up template.php from the current theme you're using and add this inside the function themename_preprocess_page(&$vars):

print_r($vars['primary_links']);exit();

And then refresh any page on the site and you'll see a print out of the primary_links array. It looks something like this:

`Array (
  [menu-640 active-trail] => Array (
    [attributes] => Array (
      [title] => A Page Title
    )
    [href] => node/20
    [title] => A Page Link Title
  )
)`

You can alter the [href] by setting it to your preferred value. You'll need to get creative with a foreach($vars['primary_links']) loop to get children and alter their parents appropriately, but it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: It doesn't work because I'm using a Nice Menus block for the primary links.

Comment: You should still be able to alter the theme function that Nice Menus uses in your template.php file to perform this. 

Look in the Nice Menus module folder for a file that ends in .tpl.php for the code to duplicate in your template.php, and/or look in the nice_menus.module for an implementation of hook_theme() which will point you to the functions that are building the menu items. If you can alter them from your own custom module or from template.php, you can play nice with Nice Menus (!) and get what you're looking for.

Comment: Good point, now I'm using Nice Menus' theme functions. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a big pain in Drupal.  My solution is to create a node specifically for the redirect page.  (I actually create a content type called Redirect so I can have pathauto treat them differently... automatically create aliases like /redirect/page-name)  After that node has been created, you can then set up a redirect from that page to the real page.

I also set up robots.txt to disallow redirect/* so that Google doesn't try to index the redirect pages if it does happen to find them.